# Either or has to have a value but both can't be null at the same time

Tags: validation, enterprise-library

I have two fields and I need to generate an attribute, using Microsoft Enterprise Library validation, so that either or has to have a value, but both can not be null at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom validator.

```
[HasSelfValidation]
public class ValidateMe {


    [SelfValidation]
    public void ValidateFieldNotNul(ValidationResults validationResults)
    {
       .. start psudo code
         if( xor)
             validationResults.AddResult( new ValidationResult("One must not be null",...));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Validation Application Block has a `PropertyComparisonValidator` which will let you compare one property with another.  Unfortunately, this validator only allows a `ComparisonType` of: `Equal, NotEqual, GreaterThan, GreaterThanEqual, LessThan, LessThanEqual` so this doesn't actually help you.

I think you have 2 options:

- Self Validation
- Custom Validator

Self Validation (shown by @Nix) is probably the easiest but would require this to be reimplemented for every scenario where you have that requirement (at least to put the hooks to call a common method).

Creating a [custom validator](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/07/26/CustomValidatorApplicationBlockSoftwareFactory.aspx) would result in code that could be added to the configuration or attributed directly on entities and that could easily be reused.

A custom validator will definitely be more work but may be worth it if you need the reuse (it can be reused across applications, for example) or prefer that design.